# Prove that an $s$ element subset of $1,2,...,n$ must have two distinct subsets with the same sum.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

A number of problems on math.stackexchange have taken the form

> Prove that an $s$ element subset of $1,2,...,n$ must have two distinct subsets with the same sum.

(For example [discrete math about Pigeonhole Principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354454/discrete-math-about-pigeonhole-principle))

Suppose that the elements of the subset are $a_1<a_2< ...<a_s.$ Then the straightforward observations that

$\,\,$ there are $2^s-1$ non-empty subsets of the $s$ element subset

$\,\,$ the possible sums range from $a_1$ to at most $a_1+\sum_{n-s+2}^n i$

proves such a result providing $$2^s-1> \frac{(2n-s+2)(s-1)}{2}+1$$ or, equivalently,
$$n<\frac{s^2-3s+2^{s+1}}{2(s-1)}.$$

This is a general result, albeit a rather weak one which can be greatly improved. I am interested in what general results can be proved for this type of problem.

> EXAMPLE $s=9$.

The above result gives $n<67.375$ i.e. $n\le67$. The result of @CalvinLin (with $a=2,b=7$) improves this to $73$.

However, this bound can be greatly improved (one general method for doing this is given as an answer). Are there other methods which are even more effective for such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to strengthen the result is to restrict the subset of $s$ to size $[a,b]$. Common use cases are where $a = 1, 2, b = s-1, s-2$ to get rid of the extreme cases.

Then, we just require

$$ \sum_{k=a}^b { s \choose k }  > bn - \frac{b^2-b}{2} - \frac{a^2+a}{2} +1 .$$

Comment: Thanks for this. I've posted a way of getting quite a large strengthening of the original result  but I'm sure there will be much better ways that I would be interested in learning about.

Answer (score 1):

Let $s=u+v+w$. (We will choose $u,v,w$ later but a choice which seems to work well is for these parameters to be roughly $\frac{s}{3},\frac{s}{6},\frac{s}{2}$.)

> Consider just those subsets which have from $u$ to $s-u$ elements.

Possible sums range from $a_1+a_2+...+a_u$ to $a_{u+1}+a_{u+2}+...+a_s$ and so we will have  two distinct subsets with the same sum unless $$a_{u+1}+a_{u+2}+...+a_s-(a_1+a_2+...+a_u)+1>\sum_{k=u}^{s-u} { s \choose k }.$$

> Now consider those subsets which include at least $v$ and at most $w$ of the elements of $\{a_{u+1},a_{u+2}, ...,a_s\}$.

Possible sums range from $a_{u+1}+a_{u+2}+...+a_{u+v}$ to $a_1+a_2+...+a_u +a_{s-w+1}+a_{s-w+2}+...+a_s$ and so we will have  two distinct subsets with the same sum unless $$a_1+a_2+...+a_u +a_{s-w+1}+a_{s-w+2}+...+a_s-(a_{u+1}+a_{u+2}+...+a_{u+v})+1>2^u\sum_{k=v}^w{ s-u \choose k }. $$

> Adding the two inequalities gives

$$2(a_{s-w+1}+a_{s-w+2}+...+a_s)+2>2^u\sum_{k=v}^w{ s-u \choose k }+\sum_{k=u}^{s-u} { s \choose k } $$
and therefore 
$$w(2n+1-w)+2>2^u\sum_{k=v}^w{ s-u \choose k }+\sum_{k=u}^{s-u} { s \choose k } $$

$$n>\frac{1}{2w}\left((w+1)(w-2)+2^u\sum_{k=v}^w{ s-u \choose k }+\sum_{k=u}^{s-u} { s \choose k } \right)$$
Therefore we will have  two distinct subsets with the same sum if 
$$n\le \frac{1}{2w}\left((w+1)(w-2)+2^u\sum_{k=v}^w{ s-u \choose k }+\sum_{k=u}^{s-u} { s \choose k } \right)$$

> EXAMPLE $s=9$.

Let $u=3,v=2,w=4$.

Then we will have  two distinct subsets with the same sum unless $n>103.75$ and so there are two such subsets for $n\le103$.

Answer (score 0):

The following result due to Erdos is a personal favorite of mine.

> Let $S$ be a finite set of positive integers such that each subset has
>   a distinct sum. Then $$\sum_{a \in S} \frac{1}a < 2. $$

The proof can be found in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077997/unexpected-proofs-using-generating-functions) stackexchange thread.

Comment: Yes a very nice result which I enjoyed reading- thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Optimal n are the sequence https://oeis.org/A276661. The links there provide upper bounds to what the maximum such n is; you are looking for the minimum.